# How to rearrange the following data using php?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

i retrieved the following data using sql query from mysql

```
TOTAL   COMPUTER        DATE        GROUP  
-----------------------------------------------
48      LAPTOP2     2009-08-19      1  
77      LAPTOP2     2009-08-20      1  
0       LAPTOP2     2009-08-21      1  
15      LAPTOP1     2009-08-19      1  
25      MAIN        2009-08-23      1  
25      LAP3        2009-08-18      2  
3       LAP3        2009-08-19      2  
55      LAP3        2009-08-20      2
```

i would like to rearrange the data like using php

```
group   computer    2009-08-18  2009-08-19   2009-08-20  2009-08-21  2009-08-22 2009-08-23  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       LAPTOP2      0          48            77         0           0          0  
1       LAPTOP1      0          15            0          0           0          0  
1       MAIN                                                                    25  
2       LAP3         25          3            55         0           0          0
```

Comment: Are you just reformatting the data, or are you aggregating totals? Your question is not clear.

Comment: yes i am aggregating totals from mysql. first one is result from mysql second one is result to be produced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query to pivot the data:

```
  SELECT t.group,
         t.computer,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.date = '2009-08-18' THEN t.total ELSE 0 END) AS '2009-08-18',
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.date = '2009-08-19' THEN t.total ELSE 0 END) AS '2009-08-19',
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.date = '2009-08-20' THEN t.total ELSE 0 END) AS '2009-08-20'
         --, etc...
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.group, t.computer
```

Your options are either to define each column for the data you are pivoting, or you can use [MySQL's Prepared Statement syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html) to dynamically create those columns.

I feel the need to point out that your example is inconsistent - for `LAPTOP2`, you have zero as the value for `2009-08-18`, but the `main` value for that is blank. Neither have a record for that date.  If you want these to show as blank/etc, change `ELSE 0 END` to `ELSE NULL END` in the `CASE` statements.

Comment: Then you can iterate over the rows in PHP

Comment: thanks for your response, is there any example dynamic column syntax

Comment: @Suriyan Suresh: Yes, see the link to the MySQL Prepared Statement documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html